# How to use "Publish artifacts to FTP" plugin in jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, ftp, jenkins-pipeline

I used to use "Publish artifacts to FTP" plugin in Freestyle project to transfer files to remote servers. Now，I want to use pipeline script,but I can't find the relevant plugin in the "Snippet Generator",and I have the same question with "SSH Publishers" plugin.

Comment: That plugin hasn't been updated in 6 years. Pipeline has been around for 2ish. I think it is safe to say that it doesn't support that natively in pipeline.

Comment: It's been a bit of a painful process trying to get SFTP publishing on Windows. If you come up with a solution other than using shell commands to run Putty, scp or sftp, then let me know.

Comment: @arjabbar, Finally ,I used cwRsync to transfer files from windows to linux,it has scp.exe and usage is the same as scp in Linux, Remember to restart Jenkins service after installation.